# How to extract "Create Date" in a faster way than with "identify"

Tags: bash

I have done a short and ugly script to create a list of photos and datetime of when it was taken.

```
identify -verbose *.JPG | grep "Image:\|CreateDate:" | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/JPG\n/JPG/g' | sed 's[^ ]* \([^ ]*\)[^0-9]*\(.*\)$/\1 \2/'
```

The output looks like

```
photo1.JPG 2018-11-28T16:11:44.06
photo2.JPG 2018-11-28T16:11:48.32
photo3.JPG 2018-11-28T16:13:23.01
```

It works pretty well, but my last folder had 3000 images and the script ran for a few hours after completing the task. This is mostly because `identify` is **very** slow. Does anyone have and alternative method? Preferably (but not exclusively) using native tools because it's a server and it is not so easy to convince the admin to install new tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lose the `grep`and `sed` and such and use `-format`. This took about 10 seconds for 500 jpgs:

```
$ for i in *jpg ; do identify -format '%f %[date:create]\n' "$i" ; done
```

Output:

```
image1.jpg 2018-01-19T04:53:59+02:00
image2.jpg 2018-01-19T04:53:59+02:00
...
```

If you want to modify the output, put the command after the `done` to avoid forking a process after each image, like:

```
$ for i in *jpg ; do identify -format '%f %[date:create]\n' "$i" ; done | awk '{gsub(/+.*/,"",$NF)}1'
image1.jpg 2018-01-19T04:53:59
image2.jpg 2018-01-19T04:53:59
...
```

Answer (score 1):

`native tools`? `identify` is the best ("native", I would call imagemagick a native tool) for this job. I don't think you'll find a faster method. Run it for 3000 images in parallel, you will have like nth-x speedup.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.JPG' | 
xargs -P0 -- sh -c "
       identify -verbose \"\$1\" |
       grep 'Image:\|CreateDate:' |
       sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/JPG\n/JPG/g' |
       sed 's[^ ]* \([^ ]*\)[^0-9]*\(.*\)$/\1 \2/'
" --
```

Or you can just use bash `for f in "*.JPF"; do ( identify -verbose "$f" | .... ) & done`.

Your seds look strange and output "unmatched ]" on my platform, I don't know what they are supposed to do, but I think `cut -d: -f2 | tr -d '\n'` would suffice. Greping for image name is also strange - you already now the image name...

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.JPG' | 
xargs -P0 -- sh -c "
       echo \"\$1 \$(
            identify -verbose \"\$1\" |
            grep 'CreateDate:' |
            tr -d '[:space:]'
            cut -d: -f2-
       )\"
" --
```

This will work for filenames without any spaces in them. I think it will be ok with you, as your output is space separated, so you assume your filenames have no special characters.

Comment: Try adding -ping after identify as it may speed up the process

Answer (score 1):

`jhead` is small, fast and a stand-alone utility. Sample output:

```
jhead ~/sample/images/iPhoneSample.JPG
```

**Sample Output**

```
File name    : /Users/mark/sample/images/iPhoneSample.JPG
File size    : 2219100 bytes
File date    : 2013:03:09 08:59:50
Camera make  : Apple
Camera model : iPhone 4
Date/Time    : 2013:03:09 08:59:50
Resolution   : 2592 x 1936
Flash used   : No
Focal length :  3.8mm  (35mm equivalent: 35mm)
Exposure time: 0.0011 s  (1/914)
Aperture     : f/2.8
ISO equiv.   : 80
Whitebalance : Auto
Metering Mode: pattern
Exposure     : program (auto)
GPS Latitude : N 20d 50.66m  0s
GPS Longitude: E 107d  5.46m  0s
GPS Altitude :  1.13m
JPEG Quality : 96
```

I did 5,000 iPhone images like this in 0.13s on a MacBook Pro:

```
jhead *jpg | awk '/^File name/{f=substr($0,16)} /^Date\/Time/{print f,substr($0,16)}'
```

In case you are unfamiliar with `awk`, that says *"Look out for lines starting with `File name` and if you see one, save characters 16 onwards as `f`, the filename. Look out for lines starting with `Date/Time` and if you see any, print the last filename you remembered and the 16th character of the current line onwards".*